# Accepted answer is at the bottom, is that a bug?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

On the Super User question *[Any command line tool checking windows domain password?](https://superuser.com/q/310835/358766)*, I noticed that the accepted answer was listed at the bottom.

Is that a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - if a question is self answered, the (self) selected answer is not automatically on top. As such its by upvotes and [in random order within answers of the same number of votes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6662/how-to-give-some-boost-to-some-really-good-answers-that-arrive-late/17606#17606)

[This is intended behaviour.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93212/self-answer-accepts-should-dock-at-the-top-like-any-other-post)

Comment: In this particular case sorting by "active" puts the accepted answer first ...