# Why is this accepted answer not at the top?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, accepted-answer, sorting

I found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1106689/how-do-i-delete-all-chrome-google-account-stored-website-passwords-at-once) from a Google search. I noticed the accepted answer is second, even though it is accepted and has significantly more votes than the "top" answer.

[This question](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12558/accepted-answer-is-at-the-bottom-is-that-a-bug) on meta says that self-answers are not automatically put at the top, however, it says in that instance it is sorted by votes.  Furthermore, a comment on the answer there says that "active" should put the accepted answer at the top anyway, which seems to be the default sort method...

Can someone explain why this is happening on this question?  I almost missed the solution to my problem due to this.

[image]

Comment: Tagged as bug until someone points out what I'm missing.

Comment: It loads OK for me. Try refreshing your browser.

Comment: Hmm, I just loaded in Incognito and it was sorted by "votes" and the accepted answer was at the top.  Is the *first* tab not the *default* tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've sorted the answers by the most active (See the active tab above the answers).

If you sort by votes, then the highest voted one is top.

Comment: Interesting.  So the first tab not the default tab?

Comment: And if sorted by votes, the accepted solution is on top regardless of votes unless it's self answered?

Comment: @ScottBeeson if self-answered, the pinning will be ignored and just follow the current sorting (as Journeyman Geek has answered).

Answer (score 4):

Its a self accepted answer. They don't automatically go on top. It only happens when its someone elses answer. Its documented in [main meta here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)